# Drupal 7 Views custom view template fields

Tags: drupal, view

I've successfully created a custom view template for my Drupal 7 site but am having issues adding attributes to the content which is outputted. I've searched high and low for the answer to this but to no avail.

I have a view called: **views-view-fields--homepage-articles.tpl.php**

I am printing content like :

```
$fields['title']->content
```

This is fine and expected, and outputs:

```
<a href="link-to-page">Title</a>
```

But I want to add classes to it - how? I'm thinking I need to write a hook, but I cannot find this documented anywhere. At the moment my solution is a string replace:

```
<?php print str_replace('<a ', '<a class="brand-blue uppercase nodecoration"', $fields['title']->content); ?>
```

As you can imagine, this is **not** a satisfactory or long-term solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add the classes to the field using [template_preprocess_views_view_fields()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7).

Edit: Couldn't do it the way I thought, but you can overwrite the output of the field like so:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'node_listing') {
    foreach ($vars['fields'] as $id => $field) {
      if ($id == 'title') {
        $field_output = l($view->result[$view->row_index]->node_title, 'node/'. $view->result[$view->row_index]->nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'brand-blue uppercase nodecoration')));

        $vars['fields'][$id]->content = $field_output;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to provide a concise example as much of that code doesn't make a lot of sense to me. A lot of it seems irrelevant to my needs.

Comment: Couldn't do it the way I was expecting to be able to, but I've given an example of how you can do it by overwriting the default output of the views style plugin.

Comment: This worked, thank you. My only concern now is that it's just a bit of a fuss to achieve what I want. Hmm. Thanks again!

Comment: James - do you know how I might access the path of an image using this method? Have been struggling with this for the best part of a day now. Thanks.

Comment: Within the foreach statement, you'll have the full image field within `$view->result[$view->row_index]` where you'll find the image uri which you can pass through to `theme_image()` or `theme_image_style()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Semantic Views? https://drupal.org/project/semanticviews - that way you can override the classes within the UI instead of template files, may suit your needs better.

Comment: I haven't - is it stable for D7? Also, in this case I would prefer to use actual template files - it's not a large site and I'd like to have more control over the markup. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried this, it's been made largely redundant by Views 3 I think, and does not offer the flexibility that I need.